What is the recommended partition size for a /root partition? [personal machine]
What is the generalized recommended size for a /root partition on a personal machine? I am trying to decide how much I should put into /root and how much into the /home partition for a Debian-based OS.
Should I put 200 GB into /root or is that way too much? How much does the average "unix" user need in their /root partition?
Thank you so much for any help you can provide.

For a home machine, I just put them all on the same partition; so on a modern machine there's the EFI System partition, a swap partition and everything else is on /.
eg
Device             Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1      2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2   1050624 974772223 973721600 464.3G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p3 974772224 976771071   1998848   976M Linux swap

You don't have "enterprise" concerns (separate /home, separate /var etc etc) and don't need to follow CIS benchmarks :-)
Separation of partitions can help in a multi-user environment because it protects the "system" from the "user"; users can fill up the disk!  But for a home user it just wastes space.

This! And for the crunch file-systems like ext4 have the 5% barrier which only root may  use when a runaway user process under /home tries to gobble up all available space ...

There are reasons that a home system may require separate partitions or filesystems. For example, gaming, content creation, programming/developing, etc that may be better kept elsewhere. It can also help in the event that the OS needs to be reinstalled as data that needs to persist can be stored on a separate partition/filesystem that is mounted elsewhere.

Isn't it required for encrypted filesystems as well?

I think any user that is new enough to ask question is better served with just / (root) not /root. Only after learning amount of space used for data, may then separate /home or data partition(s) be an option. The only other time to have separate data partitions is with the new very large multi-TB drives. Then smaller / would make sense.

@oldfred Partitioning disks and setting up filesystems isn't something that requires an extensive knowledge of any operating system. It is available when installing virtually any OS whether a Linux distro, Windows, MacOS, etc. What better time to learn more about it?
